# When does a matrix have a non-trivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone please explain why this theorem is true?

Theorem: If A is the matrix of coefficients of a system of linear equations, then the system has a solution if and only if the rank of the augmented matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $(\,A\mid b\,)$.  Reduce to row-echelon form.  The rank (for both of these) is the number of leading (pivot) columns.  Now

- the leading columns of $A$ are also leading columns of $(\,A\mid b\,)$;
- so the two ranks are different if and only if the column $b$ becomes a leading column after reduction;
- ...if and only if there is a row of the form $(\,0\,\cdots\,0\mid c\,)$ with $c\ne0$;
- ...if and only if there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is obvious if the original matrix is in row-reduced echelon form. Reducing it to that form doesn't change the rank, and it doesn't change whether the system has solutions. So it's true for any matrix.